# Parameter 'Component' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs

How to make this TypeScript compatible?

```js
export const withAppProvider = (Component) => {
    return function WrapperComponent(props) {
        return (
            <AppProvider>
                <Component {...props} />
            </AppProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For component you can use **FunctionComponent** type, it is a generic interface so you need to create an interface for your props

```
import { FunctionComponent } from 'react'

interface ComponentPropsInterface {
 ...
}

export const withAppProvider = (Component: FunctionComponent<ComponentPropsInterface>) => {
 return function WrapperComponent(props) {
    return (
        <AppProvider>
            <Component {...props} />
        </AppProvider>
    )
 }
}
```